# Is it possible 3D Transform a video clip in Final Cut Pro X?

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, plugins

All i've ever seen in Final Cut Pro is 2D Transform on a video clip. I know you can do that in After Effects but I want to stay within Final Cut Pro X to do the 3D transform.

Is there any plugins that could allow me to set a video clip in 3D Space ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple Motion will let you create "motion templates" which are usable in FCPX.  You can apply 3D transforms with Motion, and publish to Final Cut.  This approach is easy to learn, but limited in scope.

Comment: Furthermore, you can make a Motion effect and publish the 3D controls, such as the rotation around the x and y axis. Those controls will then be accessible in FCPX.